Why is comparison working in template for different sizes of const char(&)[N]?
This is a compile time error for compare1 I understand the reason.
But why doesn't it fail for compare2?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template<typename T1, typename T2>
const T1& compare1(const T1& a, const T2& b) //Can be error: if a and b of different array sizes.
{
     return a < b ? a : b;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool compare2(const T1& a, const T2& b) //Why is differenent array size error not applicable here?
{
     return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{ 
    compare1("hello", "world"); //sucess
    compare1("hello", "worldx"); //fail as expected
    compare2("hello", "worldx"); // passed which is not expected.
}

Edit: Question is why there is no error for compare2.
<source>: In instantiation of 'const T1& compare1(const T1&, const T2&) [with T1 = char [6]; T2 = char [7]]':
<source>:21:13:   required from here
   21 |     compare1("hello", "worldx");
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:19: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const char (&)[6]' from expression of type 'const char*'
   10 |      return a < b ? a : b;
      |             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~


Because an array decays to a pointer which can be converted to a bool. And so compare2 call compiles.

Note that you're actually comparing pointers and the program has undefined behavior for compare2("hello", "worldx"); GCC and msvc even gives warning saying : warning C5056: operator '<': deprecated for array types

Basically it compiles for the same reason const char a[] = "hello"; const char b[] = "worldx"; bool r = a < b ? a : b; compiles.

@user12002570 : But when I use reference will it decay to pointers?

Atleast in the compare it didn't decay to pointers so the type mismatch error. Or are you talking about the decay in the comparison?

When you use reference, the call argument is passed by reference. Inside the function however, it(the array) will still decay to a pointer.

That is why the error says: cannot convert from const char* to const char (&)[6] as a and b both decay to const char* but the return type is const char(&)[6] in case of compare1.

What's the return type of compare1? Common type of the inputs is a pointer which cannot cast to array reference, if size of input strings don't match.


why there is no error for compare2.

Because in case of compare2 the return type is bool and the operands a and b in the return statement are both arrays which can decay to pointers to char which in turn can be converted to bool.
Gcc and msvc even gives warning saying:
warning C5056: operator '<': deprecated for array types


Baiscally, it compiles for the same reason the following compiles:
const char a[] = "hello";
const char b[] = "worldx";
bool r = a < b ? a : b;

